# How do I copy and paste+transpose values from one Google Sheets sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a quality monitoring form for the business. So in one sheet (Checklist), I will be scoring interactions and in another (Raw), the scores I entered in Checklist will be compiled for reporting. As I'll be doing this several times a day, it's really a lot of work simply copying and pasting manually between Checklist & Raw.

I have  heard of recording macros, and I tried it, but I would like for the macro to not select a specific cell in the Raw sheet after pasting and transposing to avoid overwriting the information that was saved previously. Here's what the recorded macro looks like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raw'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Checklist!B1:B3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Checklist'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:D3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raw'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Checklist!D2:D3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Checklist'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D6:D19').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raw'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Checklist!D6:D19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Checklist'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
};
```

As you can see, after the macro has pasted the first entry, it specifically selects A3 in Raw:

```
  spreadsheet.getRange('Checklist!D6:D19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
```

This caused other entries to overwrite as it is calling a specific cell.

Is there a way to change that into something generic like telling Google Sheets to move one row down automatically instead of specifying a cell?

[Here's a snip of the document I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuTWY.png)

I've already manually copied and transposed values for A1-A3, and A6-onwards to the Raw sheet to serve as headers. I only need to have the macro/script copy values from B1:B3, D2, and D6: onwards to subsequent rows in the Raw sheet.

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: In situations where the data is organized for human input rather that packet together in tabular format, it's probably a lot easier to take the time to create and in and out rangeList to help you to automate the transfer process.  One thing you need to get out of the habit of using active and setActiveSheet() that habit is obtained from people who learn how to write code from macros where the system is trying to following your ever key stroke.  It's slow and cumbersome and totally unnecessary

Comment: Please share sample of desired output.